# Why don't flags on comments show up with the rest of my flags?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight, flagging

I've flagged some comments, and that have been removed.  Why can't I view the comments I've flagged?

Also how do flagged comments affect your flag weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do flagged comments affect your flag weight?

They don't.

> that have been removed. Why can't I view the comments I've flagged?

Deleted comments can be seen only by Mods. Flag weight for comments aren't recorded, so you'll  to remember by memory as to which ones you had flagged

Comment: Yes, (That part was obvious to me).  Why not though?

Comment: Dunno. Used to affect at rate of +/-5, but it [was dropped later](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100033/why-didnt-flagging-comments-affect-my-flagging-summary-or-flag-weight)